# How to get test cases from TFS project using TFS rest api version 3.2

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to get testcases from TFS and update the testcase fields in azure DevOps matching the custom ID.
1. Get test cases for particular project from TFS
2. match the custom id with azure devops testcase
3. add field values retrieved from TFS testcase in azure devops testcase.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20case%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get a specific test case in a test suite with test case id.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases/{testCaseIds}?api-version=5.0
```

According to your description, seems you just want to sync  test cases  between TFS and Azure DevOps Service. Update test step from Rest API is not easy, you could take a look my reply in this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/602844/view.html).

However, you could use some 3rd-party extension such as [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) to help you migrate your test cases to Azure DevOps Service.

Or use this extension to [TFS / Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) Test Steps Synchronization](https://confluence.spartez.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45843454)

Besides another simply method is you could directly use the **Grid View** in Azure DevOps Service.

1. Navigate to required Test Plan from web portal. Select Test Suite
   from where you want to export test cases.
2. Both in TFS and Azure DevOps Service, change View option(at top-right corner) to
   Grid.
3. Select all/required test cases in TFS grid view.
4. Paste them to Azure DevOps Service.
5. Click the Save button.